# i want to open the fragment in which music already playing without restarting the music

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

i want to open same fragment in which i started a media player without restarting it .

from here i call the fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onitemclick(int position,String sn,String ur) {
        if(pos==position)
        pos=position;
        song=sn;
        uri=ur;
        FragmentManager fm=getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.nowplaying, new playmusic(song,uri));
        ft.commit();
    }
```

and here is my fragment

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    int play;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context=context;

        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
           playsong();
        }
    }
  String songname,songuri;
    public playmusic() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public playmusic(String song,String uri){
this.songname=song;
this.songuri=uri;

    }
    
    void playsong(){
        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songuri);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

i'm passing the uri through constructor to the fragment. when ever i open the fragment it restarts the music .help me to solve the problem .

.